# Laravel api 401 Unauthorized | Only 1 device

Tags: php, android, laravel, api

I have some API endpoints in my laravel app.

They do work fine on most of my devices (phones and tablets).

A curl from the localhost also works fine.

But one phone does not work. In the logs I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
    <p>This server could not verify that you
    are authorized to access the document
    requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
    credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
    browser doesn't understand how to supply
    the credentials required.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache Server at example.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

I have no clue where the problem might be.

The API endpoints are public. They work with curl and on all other devices.

I tried changing WLAN but if all devices use the same WLAN, still that one phone does not work.
It is probably a security setting on the phone? But I have found nothing.

I am worried because if I release the project and many users will face this issue I have no clue where to look or what to do. Is this even a laravel issue?

---

I use laravel 5.8 and the API routes are in `api.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found the issue.

After many try and error I noticed that the api endpoints have a thing in common. They all work with a certain WLAN connection.

Also none of the devices work if I switch to an other WLAN connection.

Now I remembered that I have an active directory protection for the website and that the WLAN connection, which works has a static IP, which is whitelisted, so the directory protection does not trigger...

My fault. Dont forget about directory protection.